# How to loop through OpenLayers.Layer's features

Tags: openlayers

This should be easy, but when I am loading the layer as a geojson **the feature vector is empty**.

```
var geojson1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML('layer_name', '/layer_path/file_name.geojson', {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
    format: OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON});

console.log(geojson1.features.length); // the result is 0, although there are shapes showing up on the map
```

Could it be the geojson loader?

Anyway, this is how I am 100% sure that the features are there: because the following piece of code works perfectly.

```
//on click:
geojson1.events.on({
    'featureselected': function(e) {

        feature = e.feature;
        obj_name = feature.attributes.NAME;

        newAction(obj_name);

        selectCtrl.unselect(feature);

    }
});
```

The final goal of all this is to programmatically create a new attribute for each feature:

```
for(var featureCount=0; featureCount < geojson1.features.length; featureCount++){
    console.log(geojson1.features[featureCount].attributes.NAME);
    //TODO: add new attribute to feature ( geojson1.features[featureCount].attributes.ID = custom_ID )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code here for the GeoJSON read function, http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js, you will see that what it returns is either an OpenLayers.Feature.Vector or an OpenLayers.Geometry depending on the structure of the JSON. You are trying to load it into an OpenLayers.Layer.GML class, which I suspect is where the problem is. If you need GML, then you need to read the JSON in a Feature.Vector and then write that back out using the OpenLayers.Format.GML write method.

If you want to check that your JSON is valid, use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks John. After your answer I tried implement that, but I quickly realized that the problem was reading the json_str through javascript anyway. I kept digging and I found [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72986/get-features-from-openlayers-layer-vector-not-working), which is very similar to mine, and indeed it says that the geojson loader it is asynchronous and that's why you can't have access to the features right away. I will try to find a different approach. Moltes gràcies i força Barça.

Comment: Yo si. You can load json synchronously in open layers. Whether this is a good idea is another matter.

Comment: Thanks! This synchronous geojson load looks like a risky thing to do indeed. After thinking a lot about it, my guess is that my best option is to create an script that changes all my geojson files and adds the information directly there. If you know a better and effective way to organize the geojson please let me know... I have those files on the filesystem on one side, the PHP in the middle "talking" to SQL, and openlayers on the other end. A lot of headache. But I'm unaware of what else is out there. And BTW I really really hope your hunch is right :/ Let's see!

Comment: Actually, no, I think that (Geo)JSON is a very good storage format. It is supported natively in MongoDB and soon in the jsonb module of Postgres and, of course, works really well with Javascript (being a product of Javascript in the first place). How do you mean by a script that changes all your geojson files?

Comment: I meant more like a way to organize this json geographical information in SQL instead of in the filesystem. I could create a custom organization in which every json feature part is saved as a varchar, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and maybe QGIS etc have better way already... I don't know, just beating around the bush. And by a script that changes all my geojsons I mean a .NET code that reads them all and their metadata, connects to SQL and retrieves the complementary metadata I am looking for, and saves the geojson file again. Simple but difficult to maintain in the long term.